# Enviar dados sem refresh PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Eu tenho um formulário com n tabelas envolvidas e precisava deixar todos os insert em um arquivo só, bom isso eu já tenho. Mas preciso que seja enviado sem refresh e para isso estou utilizando ajax. Eis a questão como fazer isso em ajax, de uma forma que só são enviados os dados que receberam clique do botão com mesmo name no form ? Aqui vai um exemplo simples que criei agora pra demonstração da minha idéia.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
                var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "processa.php",
                        data: dados,
                        success: function( data )
                        {
                                alert( data );
                        }
                });

                return false;
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form">
        <label>Usuário: <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" /></label>
        <label>Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" value="" /></label>       
        <label><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form">
        <label>Rua: <input type="text" name="rua" value="" /></label>
        <label>Número: <input type="text" name="numero" value="" /></label>     
        <label><input type="submit" name="enviar2" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>
```

processa.php

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuar";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $resultx= "INSERT INTO usuar (usuario, senha) VALUES ('$usuario', '$senha')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $resultx);
    echo $resultx;
}


if(isset($_POST['enviar2'])){

    $rua = $_POST['rua'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM userend";
    $result = $conn->query($sql2);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $resulty = "INSERT INTO userend (rua, numero) VALUES ('$rua', '$num')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $resulty);
    echo $resulty;
}
```

Comment: começa o erro que os dois forms tem o mesmo id. ID é algo único e não pode se repetir em uma mesma página.

Comment: então mas mesmo sem o segundo form ter o id identico, o processa percorre todo arquivo ao invés de percorrer só usuário e senha, teria que ter algum ponto de parada para ele só ler o bloco usuario e senha e o segundo só ler o bloco rua e num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já foi dito em outras postagens e para quem está começando com HTML, dentro de  uma página HTML especifica nunca pode se repetir IDs, o significado de ID é provavelmente:

> **I**dentity **D**ocument (traduzido documento de identidade)

Ou seja se dois objetos tem a mesma ID já gera confusão, e funções como:

- `document.getElementById`
- `$(selector)`

Só irão considerar um dos elementos, o outro é sempre ignorado

Pra facilitar basta trocar por outro atributo, como `class` ou `data-` (html5).

Outro problema é com a função `jQuery.serialize` do jQuery, ele ignora o `type=submit`, então terá que adicionar manualmente, um exemplo:

```
var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

$("[type=submit]", this).each(function () {
     dados += "&" + escape($(this).attr("name")) + "=" + escape($(this).val());
});
```

Também recomendo usar `Event.preventDefault`

Então o código deve ficar assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ajax_form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

                $("[type=submit]", this).each(function () {
                     dados += "&" + escape($(this).attr("name")) + "=" + escape($(this).val());
                });

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "processa.php",
                        data: dados,
                        success: function( data )
                        {
                                alert( data );
                        }
                });

                return false;
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" class="ajax_form">
        <label>Usuário: <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" /></label>
        <label>Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" value="" /></label>       
        <label><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" class="ajax_form">
        <label>Rua: <input type="text" name="rua" value="" /></label>
        <label>Número: <input type="text" name="numero" value="" /></label>     
        <label><input type="submit" name="enviar2" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>
```

### Teste sem Ajax

Teste para ver o que é enviado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

        $("[type=submit]", this).each(function () {
             dados += "&" + escape($(this).attr("name")) + "=" + escape($(this).val());
        });

        console.log(dados);

        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="" class="ajax_form">
    <label>Usuário: <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" /></label>
    <label>Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" value="" /></label>       
    <label><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>

<form method="post" action="" class="ajax_form">
    <label>Rua: <input type="text" name="rua" value="" /></label>
    <label>Número: <input type="text" name="numero" value="" /></label>     
    <label><input type="submit" name="enviar2" value="Enviar" /></label>
</form>
```